# Cannot update RelativeLayout position correctly during runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I would like to change a view's position `Relative` to its parent during runtime programmatically. I created a `Spinner` to select and change the position of a `TextView`. My strategy has been resetting all possible rules (e.g. `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0)`) and then adding necessary rules required by my selection. However, except for three cases, the `TextView` has been placed in the wrong location. Here are the selections and the responses:

- Top Left -> Top Left (Working correctly)
- Top Center -> Top Left
- Top Right -> Top Left
- Middle Left -> Bottom Left
- Middle Right -> Bottom Left
- Bottom Left -> Bottom Left (Working correctly)
- Bottom Center -> Bottom Right
- Bottom Right -> Bottom Right (Working correctly)

What am I doing wrong?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="myapps.test.updateposition.MainActivity">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/mySpinner"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/helloWorld"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloWorld);
        final Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        //"Top Left","Top Center","Top Right","Middle Left","Middle Right","Bottom Left", "Bottom Center", "Bottom Right"
        list.add("Top Left");
        list.add("Top Center");
        list.add("Top Right");
        list.add("Middle Left");
        list.add("Middle Right");
        list.add("Bottom Left");
        list.add("Bottom Center");
        list.add("Bottom Right");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                setMyParams(textView, mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }

    public void setMyParams(TextView textView, String position) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
        // Reset all rules
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 0);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0);

        switch (position) {
            case "Top Left":
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            case "Top Center":
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            case "Top Right":
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            case "Middle Left":
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            case "Middle Right":
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            case "Bottom Left":
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            case "Bottom Center":
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            case "Bottom Right":
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        }
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you try using in XML first? trying create simple use case using XML. after you done, then try programmatically ways.

Comment: Post you source code into github, then i can see you code and fix it later.

Comment: @radityagumay I can use in XML with no problems, but to be able to change it during runtime it needs updating in a programmatical way. And this is all the code I've written in this application, no need to upload to GitHub. You can replicate this easily only by using the code in this post

Comment: well, you forgot using break statement.

Answer (score 0):

That's what happens when you overlook the most simple thing. I forgot to put the break statement at the end of each case.